# Laravel resource controller DELETE throws 405 with Axios

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, axios, laravel-5.5

I was working on a simple crud app using react + laravel. I am using Axios to make a request to the server. GET, POST is working fine. I am able to create a new item using POST method (axios.post). However, when I try to DELETE an item, laravel throws a 405 error, which stands for 'Method Not Allowed'

Here is my route :

`Route::resource('items', 'ItemController');`

Here is my destroy() method :

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
      $item = Item::find($id);
      $item->delete();

      return response()->json('Successfully Deleted');
    }
```

Here is my delete function which uses axios :

```
export function deleteItem(data) {
  let url = BASE_URL+'/items';
  return axios.delete(url,data).then((response) => {
    return response;
  });
}
```

I did few research on this and found that laravel understands '_method' parameter too. So I trued the below :

```
export function deleteItem(data) {
  let url = BASE_URL+'/items';
  let payload = {'id' : data, '_method' : 'DELETE'};
  return axios.post(url,payload).then((response) => {
    return response;
  });
}
```

But still no luck. It always throws 405. Any clue on this?

I am using axios & laravel at the latest version.

Comment: the thing is that resource delete in laravel  expects an id to be sent via url. So change the url to be smth along the lines: `let url = BASE_URL_'/items/'+this.id;`

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi awesome.! thanks for the clue. Works perfectly. Could you please add this as an answer.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that resource delete in laravel expects an `id` to be sent via url.

```
public function destroy($id){
   // ..find delete 
}
```

In your case you are not sending the id, therfore laravel returns a `notfoundhttpexception`

So change the url to be smth along the lines: `let url = BASE_URL_'/items/'+this.id;`

[Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers)

Comment: The exception is `methodNotAllowed`

Comment: @MahdiYounesi Resource Route for delete is Route::delete('items/{item}', 'Controller');  So when he is sending a delete request to url  base_url+'/items' route not found or NOTFOUNDHTTPEXCEPTION NOT methodnotallowed since in resource its only one delete route defined. You will get there in time you just need to learn a lil bit more. did you downvoted me ?

Comment: Sorry, i got it, edit the anwse a bit I want to take the vote back, sorry for that

Comment: @MahdiYounesi btw you should upvote my answer since you learned something new from it.

Comment: I understood my mistake. My controller is expecting/$id in the URL over DELETE request. But I was sending DELETE request just to /items URL which is obviously not defined as a route with DELETE method. Thanks once again.